# verbatim not aligned properly - XeLaTeX

Tags: verbatim

I've tried with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}%
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Path = ./ ,
UprightFont= MinionPro-Regular.otf,
BoldFont= MinionPro-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont= MinionPro-It.otf,
BoldItalicFont= MinionPro-BoldIt.otf,
]{MinionPro}%
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,}]{MinionPro-Regular}%greek,Greek
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin}]{MinionPro-It}%,greek,Greek
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=bfup/{num,latin,Latin}]{MinionPro-Bold}%,greek,Greek
\setmathfont[Numbers=Lining,range=bfit/{num,latin,Latin}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}%,greek,Greek
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Courier New}%

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
model_4bead = function(t,y,pars){
  # model_4bead = function(t,y,pars)
  # RFT dynamics for a three-link swimmer
  # y -> bx, by, theta, vbx, vby, vtheta, alpha1, alpha2
  # An eight-coordinate dynamic, only six of which are considered here
  # The other two are prescribed by the initernal gait dynamics
  # Coords
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Output generated as:

[image]

I've aligned everything correctly in `TeX` file, but in `PDF` output it was not aligned properly, please advise, how to align properly.

I'm using `Win10` and `MikTeX V2.9 - XeLaTeX` to get the output

I have many program code like this, so please advise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your quick suggestion, I did what you suggested, but still the same output only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why, but apparently `unicode-math` introduces flexibility in the interword spacing in the monospaced font, which kicks in when an overful line is found.

Solution: use the `WordSpace` feature.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\setmainfont{MinionPro}[
  Path=/Library/Fonts/,
  UprightFont= *-Regular.otf,
  BoldFont= *-Bold.otf,
  ItalicFont= *-It.otf,
  BoldItalicFont= *-BoldIt.otf,
]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{MinionPro-Regular}[
  Numbers=Lining,
  range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,}
]
\setmathfont{MinionPro-It}[
  Numbers=Lining,
  range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin}
]
\setmathfont{MinionPro-Bold}[
  Numbers=Lining,
  range=bfup/{num,latin,Latin}
]
\setmathfont{MinionPro-BoldIt}[
  Numbers=Lining,
  range=bfit/{num,latin,Latin}
]
\setmonofont{Courier New}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  WordSpace={1,0,0},
]

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
model_4bead = function(t,y,pars){
  # model_4bead = function(t,y,pars)
  # RFT dynamics for a three-link swimmer
  # y -> bx, by, theta, vbx, vby, vtheta, alpha1, alpha2
  # An eight-coordinate dynamic, only six of which are considered here
  # The other two are prescribed by the initernal gait dynamics
  # Coords
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: my solution's easier and you got the tick :(

Comment: @egreg; sir, it's working like a champ, thanks a lot

Comment: @MadyYuvi Note the “more modern” syntax for font selection. Change the `Path` for your case.

Answer (score 7):

You can demonstrate this without MinionPro (which I don't have) as warned on the terminal those two lines are over-full, unlike classic cmtt Courier New has been set with shrinkable white space and so the spaces on those lines shrink.

Set the mono font before loading unicode-math

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}%


\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Courier New}%

\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}%

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
model_4bead = function(t,y,pars){
  # model_4bead = function(t,y,pars)
  # RFT dynamics for a three-link swimmer
  # y -> bx, by, theta, vbx, vby, vtheta, alpha1, alpha2
  # An eight-coordinate dynamic, only six of which are considered here
  # The other two are prescribed by the initernal gait
  # Coords
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MadyYuvi it may be needed for your document but it wasn't needed for a _minimal_ example as if you remove it the same problem shows (If you had tried that with each line of the preamble you would have found `unicode-math` was the issue  before asking the question)  But the main sadness is giving egreg a tick:-)

Comment: Oops, sorry sir, now I understood, thanks much, your suggestion too working like a champ